# page numbering (frontmatter and mainmatter) problem

Tags: front-matter

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside,12pt, print]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage[top=5.55cm, bottom=5.55cm, left=4cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

%for the author in chapters
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother



\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=50pt

\usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\linespread{1.1}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\include{chapter1}


 \backmatter

 \appendix
 \include{scripts}

 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
 \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
 \bibliography{Reference\reference}
 \end{document}
```

***This is the CUEDthesisPSnPDF, but is not the original one, I made some changes***

```
% CUEDthesis v1.1
% By Harish Bhanderi <harish.bhanderi@cantab.net
% Version 1.0 released 15/07/2002
% Version 1.1 released 14/07/2010
%-------------------------- identification ---------------------
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}[2010/07/14 v1.1 CUED thesis class]
%-------------------------- initial code -----------------------
\newif\ifCU@bookmode
\CU@bookmodetrue

\DeclareOption{report}{\CU@bookmodefalse}
\DeclareOption{book}{\CU@bookmodetrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax%

\ifCU@bookmode
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}%
\ProcessOptions\relax%
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}%
\else%
   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}%
\fi%
\else
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}%
\ProcessOptions\relax%
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
  \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{report}%
\else%
   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{report}%
\fi%
%\renewcommand{\refname}{References}%
\fi

%\DeclareOption{book}{%
%}%
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}


\usepackage[font={small, sf},labelfont=bf]{caption}





%Bibliography
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references for Book document class
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
% note that this doesn't do much if you later define another bibliography style 


% Nomenclature
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
   \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}] }{%             A - Roman
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
     \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%             G - Greek
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%              R - Superscripts
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
           \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{{%             S - Subscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{{%    X - Other Symbols
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}%              Z - Acronyms
                        {{}}}}}}}}}}

\ifpdf
%-->
%--> Google.com search "hyperref options"
%--> 
%--> http://www.ai.mit.edu/lab/sysadmin/latex/documentation/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf
%--> http://www.chemie.unibas.ch/~vogtp/LaTeX2PDFLaTeX.pdf 
%--> http://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/ oberdiek/print/sli4a4col.pdf
%--> http://me.in-berlin.de/~miwie/tex-refs/html/latex-packages.html
%-->
    \usepackage[ pdftex, plainpages = false, pdfpagelabels, 
                 pdfpagelayout = OneColumn, % display single page, advancing flips the page - Sasa Tomic
                 bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
                 pagebackref,
                 colorlinks = true,
                 linkcolor = blue,
                 urlcolor  = blue,
                 citecolor = red,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                 hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                 ]{hyperref} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .pdf}

    \pdfcompresslevel=9
    \graphicspath{{ThesisFigs/PNG/}{ThesisFigs/PDF/}{ThesisFigs/}}
\else
    \usepackage[ dvips, 
                 bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
                 pagebackref,
                 colorlinks = true,
                 linkcolor = blue,
                 urlcolor  = blue,
                 citecolor = red,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                 hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                 ]{hyperref}

    %\usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .ps}
    \graphicspath{{ThesisFigs/EPS/}{ThesisFigs/}}
\fi

%define the page size including an offset for binding
%\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{700pt}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}


%A4 settings
\ifpdf
   \pdfpageheight=297mm
   \pdfpagewidth=210mm
\else
   \setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
   \setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\fi

%\setlength{\hoffset}{0.00cm}
%\setlength{\voffset}{0.00cm}

%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.96cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.54cm}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{1.36cm}
%\setlength{\headsep}{1.00cm}
%\setlength{\textheight}{20.84cm}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2.36cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{A thesis submitted for the degree of}}
%
%
% DECLARATIONS
%
% These macros are used to declare arguments needed for the
% construction of the title page and other preamble.

% The year and term the degree will be officially conferred
\def\degreedate#1{\gdef\@degreedate{#1}}
% The full (unabbreviated) name of the degree
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
% The name of your college or department(eg. Trinity, Pembroke, Maths, Physics)
\def\collegeordept#1{\gdef\@collegeordept{#1}}
% The name of your University
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
% Defining the crest
\def\crest#1{\gdef\@crest{#1}}

%declarations added by yaowang

%proefschrift
\def\proefschrift#1{\gdef\@proefschrift{#1}}

%defenseinfo
\def\defenseinfo#1{\gdef\@defenseinfo{#1}}

%door
\def\door#1{\gdef\@door{#1}}

%brithplace
\def\brithplace#1{\gdef\@brithplace{#1}}

%brithdate
\def\brithdate#1{\gdef\@brithdate{#1}}




% These macros define an environment for front matter that is always 
% single column even in a double-column document.

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}

%define title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\pagenumbering{roman} % Sasa Tomic
\setcounter{page}{0}  % Sasa Tomic
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
 % \null\vfill
  \begin{center}
  {\Huge{\bfseries{\@title}}\par}
  {\large \vspace*{6ex}}
  {\textbf{\large\@proefschrift}\par}
  {\large \vspace*{6ex}}

    { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
{\large \vspace*{35mm} {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{25mm}}
    {{\Large \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@university} \par}
\vspace*{25mm}
    {{\submittedtext} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}
  \null\vfill
\end{alwayssingle}}

% DEDICATION
%
% The dedication environment makes sure the dedication gets its
% own page and is set out in verse format.

\newenvironment{dedication}
{\begin{alwayssingle}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\LARGE }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{quote} \begin{center}}
{\end{center} \end{quote} \end{alwayssingle}}


% ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%
% The acknowledgements environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgements
% themselves appear in a quote environment, i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and
% on its own page.

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

% The acknowledgementslong environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgement itself 
% does not appears in a quote environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{acknowledgementslong}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%ABSTRACT
%
%The abstract environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself appears in a quote environment,
%i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and on its own page.

\newenvironment{abstracts} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractlong environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself does not appears in a quote
%environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{abstractslong} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm} \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractseparate environment is for running of a page with the abstract
%on including title and author etc as required to be handed in separately

\newenvironment{abstractseparate} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-1in}
 \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {{\large \vspace*{1ex} \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}
    {{\@university} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\it \submittedtext} \par}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}

%ROMANPAGES
%
% The romanpages environment set the page numbering to lowercase roman one
% for the contents and figures lists. It also resets
% page-numbering for the remainder of the dissertation (arabic, starting at 1).

\newenvironment{romanpages}
{\setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}
%{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}
```

this is my script,it should be roman number before chapter1, but there are two pages in arabic number in the last of figures section. therefore, the page number in the chapter1 start with the arabic number "3".

could you tell me where is wrong?

Comment: Use `\cleardoublepage \mainmatter` to ensure you start fresh with Arabic numbering.

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: Great. Then you should provide us with a *complete*, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem, otherwise it's anyone's guess what might be going on.

Comment: *Complete* means starting with `\documentclass` and terminating with `\end{document}`,

Comment: Is the `CUEDthesisPSnPDF` document class available online?

Comment: I added the script of class inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. It is not about the latex script, but about the encode. I found only the introduction chapter caused the problem, therefore, I checked what kinds of encoding used, and compared to other latex files. the introduction latex file is UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, while others are ASCII. therefore I first converted it to UTF-8 without BOM and it worked. I do not know what exactly difference between UTF-8 and UTF-8 with BOM, but it led the problem.